# Discard pile and shuffling question

Tags: dominion

Say I have a hand like follows: Estate, Upgrade, Upgrade, Estate, Copper. 1 card in Draw pile.

I play Upgrade (+1 card, +1 action) -> Draw the last card from my Draw pile -> Trash Estate from my hand and gain a Silver card. This silver card goes into discard. So far so good.

Now, I play my second Upgrade. Since there's no card in my Draw pile, I need to shuffle my Discard pile. Do I shuffle my silver card that I just gained or does do I leave it in the "discard-of-the-current-turn" pile.

The general question is, if I need to shuffle my discard, do I shuffle all cards that I gained during the current turn? I know that I do not shuffle cards that I have set aside.

Comment: I feel like I have seen this question here before... but was unable to find it via searching.

Comment: I went through all questions that are tagged "dominion" and couldn't find it.

Comment: Yeah, I am not blaming you for anything. I just could have sworn I saw this question here. Maybe it was on another site...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You include the card you just gained when re-shuffling.  There is only one discard pile.

Cards that are set aside or revealed do not get re-shuffled until they are placed in the the discard pile as specified by the specific card.

Quotes from the [rulebook](http://www.riograndegames.com/uploads/Game/Game_278_gameRules.pdf):

> "Gain” – when a player gains a card, he takes the gained card (usually from
>   the Supply) and puts it onto his Discard pile (unless the card says to put
>   it elsewhere). The player does not get to use the card when he gains it.

---

> A player places cards he Buys or otherwise acquires during the
>   game on his Discard pile unless he is specifically directed to place
>   them elsewhere.

Comment: This is correct. Another odd end-case is Island or Native Village: You can end up setting aside a card you just gained.

Comment: I actually used this in several games - to draw all of my deck, and then gain a card and immediately put it into play by drawing one more card.